How can I add a macro to the model?
In Laravel, models have a getTable function that allows us to query the table associated with the model. In some cases, I need to ensure that I don't use this function, but instead strictly query the actual table name. (If a database name property is specified for a model, the result of getTable will be databaseName.tableName.)
To avoid duplication, I thought I could elegantly attach a macro to the model, but I was disappointed to find that this is not possible for abstract classes. How can I achieve this?
The desired outcome would be to add the macro to the Laravel Model class, making it available across all my models.

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Get the table associated with the model.
 * Without database name. (strict only table name)
 *
 * @return string
 */
Model::macro('getStrictTable', function () {
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $this */
    $tableNameParts = explode('.', $this->getTable());
    return end($tableNameParts);
});


Cannot instantiate abstract class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model


If nothing works, create a class that extends the base Model and add this method. Later, all your models will extend your custom class.

You could put this method in a trait to use on the User model.

You can only create a macro for the class that uses the trait Macroable. The model does not use that trait as it is a abstract class. Like others suggested you can create your own trait and use that in the models required.
I thnk you should macro the Eloquent Builder it might work for your case.

All of these are great solutions if I only need macros for some of the models or a specific model. However, I am primarily looking for a global solution that allows me to create macros for all models without any additional modifications. Anuj's solution is already heading in this direction; I just wish I could directly extend Laravel's default model. Undoubtedly, extending the Builder seems like a good approach.

After I wrote my comment I thought why not try it :) so it worked using the Eloquent Builder.
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

 Builder::macro('getStrictTable', fn() => Str::afterLast($this->getModel()->getTable(), '.'));

Then you can just do
\App\Models\User::getStrictTable();

You can also use it after you have fetched the model eg:
\App\Models\User::find(1)->getStrictTable();

So you are eloquently fetching the "strict" table name.
To summarize, you cannot use the macro if the class does not use Macroable trait, and the model is an abstract class it is not possible to add any macro to it.
